# Why can't I find the AjaxControlToolkit Html Editor Control using FindControl when it's inside an AjaxControlToolkit ReorderList?

Tags: asp.net, controls, ajaxcontroltoolkit, reorderlist, html-editor

I have the latest release of the AjaxControlToolkit, and am using an AjaxControlToolkit Html Editor control inside an AjaxControlToolkit ReorderList.  I need to be able to access the "content" property so I can write the value to the database but FindControl doesn't find it.

for instance, I **can find** a **TextBox control** inside the ItemCommandEvent:

```
Protected Sub IncludedSectionComponentsReorderList_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.ReorderListCommandEventArgs) Handles IncludedSectionComponentsReorderList.ItemCommand

 If e.CommandName = "SaveChanges" Then

        Dim txtSectionComponentLabel As TextBox = CType(e.Item.FindControl("txtSectionComponentLabel"), TextBox)

 End If End Sub
```

But I **can't find** an AjaxControlToolkit Html Editor in the same event:

```
Protected Sub IncludedSectionComponentsReorderList_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.ReorderListCommandEventArgs) Handles IncludedSectionComponentsReorderList.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "SaveChanges" Then

         Dim editor As Editor = CType(e.Item.FindControl("3Editor"), Editor)
                strSectionControlValue = editor.Content

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the AjaxControlToolKit ReorderList control before, but you may need to access something like the "_OnItemDataBound" event. Sometimes controls are shoved in there when a row is being databound and you can't access them as you would think.

Good luck and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for you:

In this example it's taking content from an aspx page to an ascx page

```
    AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor txtNotes = (AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor)Page.FindControl("txtNotes");
    txtView.Content = txtNotes.Content;
```